# OData query for graph security alert_v2 resource for collection properties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata, azure-ad-graph-api

i'm trying to query new **alert_v2** resource type of microsoft graph api using Odata query. I'm particularly having difficulty creating query string for collection type properties. I can't seem to get past `Invalid filter clause` error. I used odata $filter query parameter with lambda operator just like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=http

```
(fileEvidence/any(query1:tolower(query1/fileDetails/fileName) eq 'test.txt')) and (createdDateTime ge 2023-04-25T17:19:28.918Z and createdDateTime le 2023-04-25T17:24:28.918Z))
```

here's the api resource link where properties are listed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-list-alerts_v2?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-list-alerts_v2?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters), only `assignedTo`, `classification`, `determination`, `createdDateTime`, `lastUpdateDateTime`, `severity`, `serviceSource` and `status` are supported in the `$filter` query.

Also there is no property `fileEvidence` only `evidence` property which can be of type [fileEvidence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/security-fileevidence?view=graph-rest-1.0). So filtering `evidence` items by a type should be necessary.

You can try the following query but it don't expect it will work because `security/alerts_v2` endpoint obviously doesn't support all OData functions.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts_v2?$filter=(evidence/any(ev:isof(ev, 'microsoft.graph.security.fileEvidence') and tolower(ev/fileDetails/fileName) eq 'test.txt')) and (createdDateTime ge 2023-04-25T17:19:28.918Z and createdDateTime le 2023-04-25T17:24:28.918Z))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Yeah it doesn't work. I was in the impression that this alert_v2 works the same as the legacy alert resource where you can search all the properties.